# Migrating Authorization Mechanics ClientLogin to OAuth2 Google AdWords v201206 Perl

Tags: perl, authorization, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

So I previously was using [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps) for authorization in the Google AdWords API but after looking at [AuthForInstalledApps](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps) it says that this mechanism has been deprecated in favor of [OAuth2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)

I have registered my application in the [API Consoles](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).  Now I am trying to follow the perl example of how to set this up:

[use_oauth2.pl](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-perl/source/browse/trunk/examples/v201206/misc/use_oauth2.pl)

I cannot place the AdWords Client, credentials in  [~/adwords.properties](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-perl/source/browse/trunk/adwords.properties) since I have multiple accounts that I will be doing Campaign Management operations on, and therefore multiple client ids.

But for now I tried to follow this example by using just one of my client's info like this:

```
my $client = Google::Ads::AdWords::Client->new(
    {
        version  => 'v201206',
        developer_token => TOKEN,
        client_id => $google_account_id
    }
);

$client->get_auth_token_handler()->set_email($login);
$client->get_auth_token_handler()->set_password($password);
```

However when I step through this, when it tries to initialize the `Client` object it throws this error:

```
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at (eval 845)[/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/HTTP/Message.pm:371] line 1. at (eval 845)[/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/HTTP/Message.pm:371] line 1
HTTP::Message::__ANON__[(eval 845)[/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/HTTP/Message.pm:371]:1]() called at /home/etienne/backend/libs/Google/Ads/Common/HTTPTransport.pm line 30
Google::Ads::Common::HTTPTransport::client('Google::Ads::Common::HTTPTransport=HASH(0xb59b830)', 'Google::Ads::AdWords::Client=SCALAR(0x9b9bb60)') called at /home/etienne/backend/libs Google/Ads/AdWords/Client.pm line 180
Google::Ads::AdWords::Client::START('Google::Ads::AdWords::Client=SCALAR(0x9b9bb60)', 1, 'HASH(0xb582e70)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Class/Std/Fast.pm line 251
Class::Std::Fast::__ANON__[/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Class/Std/Fast.pm:252]() called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Class/Std/Fast.pm line 287
Class::Std::Fast::new('Google::Ads::AdWords::Client', 'HASH(0xb54c210)') called at /home/etienne/backend/search_marketing/data_exchange/lib/GoogleAPIv2.pm line 3555
GoogleAPIv2::get_adwords_client('GoogleAPIv2=HASH(0xb556d10)', 4202697829) called at /home/etienne/backend/search_marketing/data_exchange/lib/GoogleAPIv2.pm line 230
GoogleAPIv2::add_campaign('GoogleAPIv2=HASH(0xb556d10)', 'name', 'API Upgrade Test Campaign - 1348613850', 'google_account_id', 4202697829, 'account_id', 207, 'country_code', 'US', ...) called at google_add_campaign.t line 110
main::main() called at google_add_campaign.t line 26
scalar context return from CODE(0x9b909c0): *Class::Std::Fast::_cache
1..3
```

I am using `Perl v5.8.8` .  I have installed the latest `Adwords Perl Client Library v2.7.2` .  Is there some kind of dependency issue?
And how can I go about resolving this issue.  Any information you can provide would be very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: According to the [CPAN Testers Results](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/G/GOOGLE-ADWORDS-PERL-CLIENT.html#GOOGLE-ADWORDS-PERL-CLIENT-2.7.2) for [Google::Ads::AdWords::Client](https://metacpan.org/module/Google::Ads::AdWords::Client) it has not been tested for Perl 5.8.8. The newest (successfully tested) version is 5.8.9. This may be unrelated, but could also be it, since the problem traces down to a standard module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I just needed to have the latest [HTTP/Message.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.03/lib/HTTP/Message.pm) `v6.0.3` module installed since the version I had installed did not have the method `decode()` which was being passed to the `AUTOLOAD()` subroutine in the `HTTP/Message.pm` module.